# Use group_by to create separate dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to xtable groups of a dataframe separately.  It seems like `dplyr`'s `group_by()` is a great way to go, but I think I need a way to create separate dataframes.

in pseudocode:

```
library(dplyr)
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
# does something like this exist?
grouped_dfs_list <- create_separate_dfs(by_cyl) 
xtable(grouped_dfs_list[[1]])
xtable(grouped_dfs_list[[2]])
xtable(grouped_dfs_list[[3]])
```

does something like `create_separate_dfs()` exist?  Ideally it would return a list of dataframes, i guess.

Comment: I don't think so, dplyr is about transforming dataframes into dataframes. `tapply` with `simplify = F` might be a better option here

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the do function within dplyr. However, I think plyr's dlpy sounds more like something that fits the pattern you're trying to achieve. For example, would out <- dlply(mtcars, .(cyl), xtable) do what you're after?

Comment: That's perfect -- `dlply` has exactly the behavior i'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `split`:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=2), val=letters[1:6])
split(df, df$id)

#$`1`
#  id val
#1  1   a
#2  1   b

#$`2`
#  id val
#3  2   c
#4  2   d

#$`3`
#  id val
#5  3   e
#6  3   f
```

Comment: base r! who'd have thunk!